# Remove new line character from C# String

Tags: c#

I have following string.

```
    string str = @"One
Two

Four
Five
Six
Seven
Eight




Thirteen






Twenty


";
```

I want to remove the extra new lines in this string. So that the string should look like:

```
str = "One
Two
Four
Five
Six
Seven
Eight
Thirteen
Twenty"
```

I am using this code but it is not working.

```
 Str = Str.Replace("\n\n", "\n");
           while (Str.IndexOf("\n") > 0)
            {
                Str = Str.Replace("\n\n", "\n");
            }
```

I even tried with  `Str = Str.Replace("\u000a\u000a", "\u000a");` But still it didn't worked out.

Comment: I am not sure right now, is the first parameter regex? If yes, this should work `Str.Replace("[\n]+", "\n");` or maybe including the spaces : `Str.Replace("[ ]*[\n]+[ ]*", "\n");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could split the string into lines, remove the empty entries and join it back together:

```
var lines = str.Split('\n')
                .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));

str = string.Join("\n", lines);
```

Comment: +1, but use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` instead of `string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Trim())`

Comment: @DavidG: Your code is not working properly. I am getting errors:
1.The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments.
2.Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'.

Comment: @Kami I've just pasted the code in exactly as written above and it worked. Perhaps you are missing an import, add `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: @DavidG: Thanks for the comment. I figure out the problem. I am using Dot Net Verison 3.5. I will update the Target Framework to version 4.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
str = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, "(" + Environment.NewLine + ")+", Environment.NewLine)
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) to learn more about `Environment.Newline`. But even the above code does not guarantee to remove duplicate newlines, because the document or string you are parsing could be created on different machine where the code for a newline is diferent:

- `"\r\n"` - windows newline,
- `"\n"` - unix newline,
- `"\r`" - mac newline

For introduction to regular expression, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) article should be quite informative, but generally:

- `Environment.Newline` can be of multiple characters, such as `"\r\n"` and thats why I am enclosing this variable in `"()"` to mark it as a group of characters (single element) which should be considered atomic,
- `"+"` matches the preceding element (`Environment.Newline` enclosed in `"()"`) one or more times.

Thanks to above and to [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) we get exactly the desired output.

Comment: The problem with this is it doesn't cope with 3 or more newlines.

Comment: Better, but perhaps an explanation of the regex for the uninitiated?

Comment: @MichalHosala Thanks for the answer but your solution is not Generic. Please see my updated answer. This is the string for which your solution doesn't work.

Comment: @Kami I rewieved your updated question and still don't understand why my answer is not good for you as it provides the desired output, could you please explain in a more detail?

Comment: @MichalHosala I tried your solution with the string and I can still see the extra lines.

Comment: @Kami then you probably are not using standard windows newlines `\r\n` but `\n` instead .. If so then just replace `Environment.NewLine` in the code above with `"\n"` and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it hangs at the while. Which is to be expected as the replace will never get rid of all of the `\n` instances. You want to change your current while loop to this:

```
while (str.IndexOf("\n\n") > 0)
{
    str = str.Replace("\n\n", "\n");
}
```

This will loop until any repeated instances of `\n\n` have been removed.

Edit: I've tested this and for a variety or cases and it works as long as the string does not start with `\n` or `\n\n`.